# Linux User space application to access G_zero gadget driver

Tags: linux

I am using the USB peripheral mode in Linux board. I have successfully port the g_zero gadget driver on Linux supported board and successfully enumeration with host PC. Now I want to send the raw data of video[camera] using g_zero gadget driver from user space Application.

I have been lot's of searching on Google but i didn't found anything. **Please guide me any one who have been done same type of work on gadget driver.**

Thanks & Best Regards;
Nikunj Patel

Answer (score 0):

For video streaming you should rather use uvc gadget rather than g_zero (which only can loopback data from host or transfer zeros, depending on configuration).

Also, [this github project](https://github.com/lintwins/uvc-gadget) seem to be complete example for controlling such gadget from user space.